# How to hide title produc on site?

Tags: wordpress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGdyc.png
same : i.stack.imgur.com/7Cogs.png

I wait hide it
how to ?
i want hide it on site me , and only show price

Comment: Header must be english!!!

Comment: Is this even your website? And you must show us your code for us to help you.

Comment: yes , is website me 
z2best.com <-- i wait hide title production

Comment: same : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cogs.png

Comment: Only show price

Answer (score 0):

Get the css selector and use display none.

```
.your-product-title{
  display: none;
}
```